# non connected subsets of $X \times X$ , $X$ is cofinite.

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

I was asked the following:

> Are there any infinite subsets of $X \times X$ which are not
>   connected? $X$ is given the cofinite topology, and $X \times X$ is
>   given the product topology.

edit: $X$ *is* connected, as there are no disjoint nonempty open connected sets. But this holds too for the basis elements of $X \times X$ isn't it? So all such subsets are connected?

Comment: Why do you think $X$ isn't connected?

Comment: If $X$ is infinite, $X$ is connected since a nonempty open subset is cofinite, and for it to be also closed and not the whole space, it would have to be finite which gives a contradiction.

Comment: Base elements connected does not mean that the space is connected, just locally connected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the product of X and any multi-point finite subset of
X, is an infinite subset of XxX that is not connected.
X itself is hyperconnected
(every intersection of two not empty open sets is not empty).

Comment: How is this relevant for subsets of $X \times X$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma It is a generalization of your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Note that for any $x \neq y \in X$ we have that $\{x,y\} \times X \subset X \times X$ (infinite if $X$ is) is disconnected; its connected components are exactly the sets $\{x\} \times X$ and $\{y\} \times X$. You could also use that $A \times B$ is connected iff $A$ and $B$ are connected, and all finite subsets of $X$ are disconnected (discrete).